# Trying to find a a perfect number within an upper limit in java without creating a method

Tags: java, numbers

I'm just trying to print the perfect numbers within a certain upper limit, but I get other numbers that show up, that aren't perfect numbers. I'm not trying to use a method, rather than just everything in the main loop. I need some help.

```java
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    int upper;
    int sum = 0;   
    int i;
    System.out.println("Enter upper limit");
    Scanner stnd = new Scanner(System.in);
    upper = stnd.nextInt();
    
    for(int n = 1; n < upper;  n++) {
      i = 1;
      sum = 0;

      while (i <= n/2) {
        if (n%i == 0) {
          sum = sum + i;  
        }
        i++;
    
        if(sum == n) {      
          System.out.println(n+" is a perfect number");
          break;
        } else {
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the largest number you're trying to store in an `int`?

Comment: yes im trying to store in an int

Comment: As a general strategy, you might try using a method and then in-lining it if you really don’t want it (might require a stack plus loop if you have recursion).  I might also start by cleaning up your indentation, and maybe running through a debugger or adding some more println statements

Comment: Yes, I can see you're trying to store in an int.  What is the LARGEST number you're trying to store?

Comment: Also, what are the non perfect numbers you are getting, and for what input?

Comment: when in put the upper limit as 100, I get 6 , 24, and 28, when it should be just 6 & 28

Comment: the largest number I would say is 100, doesn't really matter im just trying to find the perfect numbers that come up to that largest number

Comment: Your problem is that your `if` block that prints the message is inside the `while` loop, but it should be outside.  I should probably write that as an answer!

Comment: (And the  reason for my earlier question was that if you were trying to store numbers above about 2 billion in an `int`, you could have got problems with integer overflow - I've seen people write programs that try to store 20 digit numbers in `int` variables, then wonder why the arithmetic doesn't work out)

Comment: I feel like this could be a good example of where creating a method reduces the likelihood of a bug.  I’d extract out some of the logic into a method called sumOfAllFactors(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a `while` loop in your code that adds up the factors of the number.  The problem is that you're checking the sum, when the `while` loop isn't yet finished.  In the case of 24, you've added up

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 8
```

which is 24, but your loop hasn't got to 12 yet.

You need to move

```
if(sum == n) {      
     System.out.println(n+" is a perfect number");
}
```

to after the `while` loop, rather than having it inside the loop.

Comment: now its only printing 6 when the input is a 100

Comment: I hope you threw away the `break;` - if you didn't, it would break out of the `for` loop.